# What is the meaning of go places in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

**Boy**: Why do you ride a bike?

**Mom**: **To go places**.

**Boy**: Well, you can **go places** on foot; you can walk.

**Mom**: Yes, if I want to go fast I ride my bicycle.

**Boy**: Why?

**Mom**: Because riding my bicycle is faster than walking.
Walking is too slow.

**Boy**: Why do you want to go fast?

**Mom**: Because if I want to go very far, **travel** a long way,
it's quicker to go by bicycle.

**Boy**: Is the bicycle the quickest way to **travel**?

**Mom**: Oh, no, there are lots of ways to **travel**.

---

What does "**go places**" mean in this dialogue?

Does it mean "**go somewhere**"?

Comment: It's just an informal expression for 'travel around, go [to different] places'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting- Can we consider this phrase as two individual words?
-Can we divide this phrase into two separate words?

Comment: I don't know what you mean - a phrase is, by definition,  a combination of several words.

Comment: In the specific context here, ***to go places*** is an entirely *literal* usage. But it's very often used more metaphorically to mean [***to become very successful***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Going+Places). In both cases though, it's become something of a "set phrase" within which we've discarded the natural preposition *to go **to** places*.

Comment: @Kate Bunting-You're right. We can't divide a phrase into two separate words. I mean we usually travel by train, plane, bus ... we don't travel on foot. We usually go near places on foot or bicycle. Is "go places" a phrase in this dialogue?

Comment: It's not an expression I use much myself, but I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the distance travelled. The mother is just saying that she uses her bicycle to get to wherever she needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

To *go somewhere* is to go to some particular place. To *go places* is to go to more than one place, maybe many places.

To go somewhere... to go to the market to buy groceries (for example).

To go places... to go to the market, to go and visit Uncle Leo, to go to the library, to go to school for classes, to go to the beach for a swim on hot days... for examples.